# Does emacs use a global string cache?

Tags: emacs, global-variables

I think the answer is no since the result of

```
(eq "a" "a")
```

is `nil`.  So, does this mean it would be faster to create a single constant symbol holding a string and byte-compile everything using the symbol instead of the actual string?  I'm not sure how to test this properly.

Comment: Wrt part of your question: Yes, it is quicker to compare symbols (using `eq`) than strings (including the strings that name symbols).

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong. Strings are costly in Emacs Lisp. Symbols and buffers are not costly. And if you need to, you can make your own obarrays, which are, in effect, symbol sets and namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elisp *reader* creates a new object whenever it reads a string literal.

The reader converts `(eq "a" "a")` into a list of three objects for subsequent evaluation: the interned symbol `eq`, and two string objects.

The two string objects are `equal` and `string-equal` because they have equivalent values; but they are different objects, so they are not `eq`.

Comment: The reader is what converts (once) the text you write into lisp objects which can be evaluated (repeatedly). i.e. The text you write is not evaluated directly, and there are rules governing what the reader produces -- e.g. string literals are read as independent objects, while equal integers are read as the same object -- which have consequences for the evaluation phase. Without understanding the distinction between the Read and Evaluate phases, certain aspects of lisp can prove very confusing. (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20535 is a good example.)

Comment: With the caveat that I'm no expert on byte-compilation, so far as I understand it the byte-compiled code still goes through the same read process that uncompiled code goes through (or at least *a* read process). The compiled form is certainly more efficient during execution, but if its behaviour wasn't equivalent to the uncompiled form, that would be a huge problem, so I don't think it's as gray an area as you might think.